# Unescaping a HTML entity of a Japanese character on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, unicode, java-me, character-encoding

Basically I am reading in a JSON string which contains a html entity like this: `&#19968;` 
And but in my app that is not useful. I need this: `一` (Japanese character for 1)

What is the best way to do this?
Both the JSON and my app are using UTF-8

I've parsed out the `int` so now I basically have `int i = 19968;`

I tried casting to a char, converting to hex and then casting to a char.
but nothing works..

help.

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was a simulator issue. I somehow changed simulators.. and assumed the EastAsia simulator would support kanji, but it just drew boxes..

Answer (score 0):

try following code :

```
    int i = 19968;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
    bytes[0] = (byte)((i >>> 8) & 0x00ff); 
    bytes[1] = (byte)( i & 0x00ff);

    String str = null;
    try {
        str = new String(bytes, "Unicode");
        // System.out.println(str);
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        uee.printStackTrace();
    }
```